# SharePoint 2013 how to get person field value from another lookup of that list?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest, sharepoint

[image: Budget Region List]
[image: Budget List]

Now in BudgetRegion list Director is Person type field so I am not able to take a lookup of it in Budgets list.
In rest API with one AJAX call on Budget list I can easily get Title of Region but I want Director name also.
How can I get that ?
I am trying something like this, but this is not working.

```js
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Budgets')/Items?$select=ID,BudgetYear,BudgetPriorYear,BudgetTargetYear,BudgetRegions/Title,BudgetRegions/Director&$expand=BudgetRegions",
```

Can any one solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't expanding things properly. Try this:

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Budgets')/Items?$select=ID,BudgetYear,BudgetPriorYear,BudgetTargetYear,BudgetRegions/Title,Director/Title&$expand=BudgetRegions,Director",
```

Answer (score 0):

try _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Getuserbyid(" + TheIDofTheUser + ")";

I believe you need the UserID to get a person field.